# Crash on tap of didSelectRow for going to another viewcontroller

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have a tableview with 4 rows and on clicking the 4th row, I want to go to another viewcontroller. This is what I have written in `didSelectRow..`

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

    if indexPath.row == 3 {
      let groupListViewController = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed(String(describing: GroupListViewController.self),
                                                                owner: self,
                                                                options: nil)?[0] as! GroupListViewController

      self.navigationController?.pushViewController(groupListViewController, animated: true)
    }
  }
```

But on tapping the row, it crashes at this line with the error `Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value`:

```
  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell: ShareOptionsTableViewCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellID) as! ShareOptionsTableViewCell //CRASH HERE

....
...

return cell
}
```

What is going wrong...?

Comment: Check whether `groupListViewController` is `nil` or not.

Comment: Is this `cellForRowAt` inside `GroupListViewController`?

Comment: Have you registered a nib with the tableView for cellID?

Comment: Also check that the value of 'cellID' is not nil and matches the string of the cell reuse identifier in storyboard (if using storyboard)

Comment: can you please add error from log?

Comment: I had not registered the nib..That was the issue..:) . Thanks guys..

Answer (score 0):

As my thought, the `Nib` that you named is different than in your **GroupListViewController.swift** file and it crashes when you're trying to unwrap the `groupListViewController` that can not be found with that name.

In this case, you could recheck the name of your `Nib` or your Swift file **GroupListViewController.swift** and to prevent the crash you could use `guard` to check against `nil` before using.

```
guard let viewController = Bundle.main.loadNibNamed("NameOfTheNib", owner: nil, options: nil)?.first else {
        print("Can not find nib with that name")
        return
    }
```

Comment: Actually @anhtran..as I mentioned in the comment, the issue was I had not registered the nib only....